# How to convert a python string

Tags: python, string, escaping

How would I convert this string

```
'\\n    this is a docstring for\\n    the main function.\\n    a,\\n    b,\\n    c\\n    '
```

into

```
'\n    this is a docstring for\n    the main function.\n    a,\n    b,\n    c\n    '
```

keeping in mind I would also like to do this for '\t' and all other escaped characters.
The code for the reverse way is

```
def fix_string(s):
    """ takes the string and replaces any `\n` with `\\n` so that the read file will be recognized """
    # escape chars = \t , \b , \n , \r , \f , \' , \" , \\
    new_s = ''
    for i in s:
            if i == '\t':
                    new_s += '\\t'
            elif i == '\b':
                    new_s += '\\b'
            elif i == '\n':
                    new_s += '\\n'
            elif i == '\r':
                    new_s += '\\r'
            elif i == '\f':
                    new_s += '\\f'
            elif i == '\'':
                    new_s += "\\'"
            elif i == '\"':
                    new_s += '\\"'
            else:
                    new_s += i
    return new_s
```

would I possibly need to look at the actual numeric values for the characters and check the next character say if I find a ('\',92) character followed by a ('n',110)?

Comment: Do you have the order of the two strings backwards?

Comment: consider using `str.replace`.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense - no. I am just giving an example of how I would do this the reverse way.

Comment: Does your string *actually* contain the three characters `'\\n'`? Or is it appearing in some escaped form?

Comment: `str.replace(r'\\', r'\')` ?

Comment: @Kevin - wow sometimes its hard to see something so obvious. thnks.

Comment: @hughdbrown, that throws an error

Comment: why does this get a negative vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel here. Python has your back. Besides, handling escape syntax *correctly*, is harder than it looks.

### The correct way to handle this

In Python 2, use the str-to-str [`string_escape` codec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#id6):

```
string.decode('string_escape')
```

This interprets any Python-recognized string escape sequences for you, including `\n` and `\t`.

Demo:

```
>>> string = '\\n    this is a docstring for\\n    the main function.\\n    a,\\n    b,\\n    c\\n    '
>>> string.decode('string_escape')
'\n    this is a docstring for\n    the main function.\n    a,\n    b,\n    c\n    '
>>> print string.decode('string_escape')

    this is a docstring for
    the main function.
    a,
    b,
    c

>>> '\\t\\n\\r\\xa0\\040'.decode('string_escape')
'\t\n\r\xa0 '
```

In Python 3, you'd have to use the [`codecs.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.decode) and the `unicode_escape` codec:

```
codecs.decode(string, 'unicode_escape')
```

as there is no `str.decode()` method and this is not a str -> bytes conversion.

Demo:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> string = '\\n    this is a docstring for\\n    the main function.\\n    a,\\n    b,\\n    c\\n    '
>>> codecs.decode(string, 'unicode_escape')
'\n    this is a docstring for\n    the main function.\n    a,\n    b,\n    c\n    '
>>> print(codecs.decode(string, 'unicode_escape'))

    this is a docstring for
    the main function.
    a,
    b,
    c

>>> codecs.decode('\\t\\n\\r\\xa0\\040', 'unicode_escape')
'\t\n\r\xa0 '
```

### Why straightforward `str.replace()` won't cut it

You *could* try to do this yourself with `str.replace()`, but then you also need to implement proper escape parsing; take `\\\\n` for example; this is `\\n`, escaped. If you naively apply `str.replace()` in sequence, you end up with `\n` or `\\\n` instead:

```
>>> '\\\\n'.decode('string_escape')
'\\n'
>>> '\\\\n'.replace('\\n', '\n').replace('\\\\', '\\')
'\\\n'
>>> '\\\\n'.replace('\\\\', '\\').replace('\\n', '\n')
'\n'
```

The `\\` pair should be replaced by just one `\` characters, leaving the `n` uninterpreted. But the replace option either will end up replacing the trailing `\` together with the `n` with a newline character, *or* you end up with `\\` replaced by `\`, and then the `\` and the `n` are replaced by a newline. Either way, you end up with the wrong output.

### The slow way to handle this, manually

You'll have to process the characters one by one instead, pulling in more characters as needed:

```
_map = {
    '\\\\': '\\',
    "\\'": "'",
    '\\"': '"',
    '\\a': '\a',
    '\\b': '\b',
    '\\f': '\f',
    '\\n': '\n',
    '\\r': '\r',
    '\\t': '\t',
}

def unescape_string(s):
    output = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        c = s[i]
        i += 1
        if c != '\\':
            output.append(c)
            continue
        c += s[i]
        i += 1
        if c in _map:
            output.append(_map[c])
            continue
        if c == '\\x' and i < len(s) - 2:  # hex escape
            point = int(s[i] + s[i + 1], 16)
            i += 2
            output.append(chr(point))
            continue
        if c == '\\0':  # octal escape
            while len(c) < 4 and i < len(s) and s[i].isdigit():
                c += s[i]
                i += 1
            point = int(c[1:], 8)
            output.append(chr(point))
    return ''.join(output)
```

This now can handle the `\xhh` and the standard 1-letter escapes, but not the `\0..` octal escape sequences, or `\uhhhh` Unicode code points, or `\N{name}` unicode name references, nor does it handle malformed escapes in quite the same way as Python would.

But it *does* handle the escaped escape properly:

```
>>> unescape_string(string)
'\n    this is a docstring for\n    the main function.\n    a,\n    b,\n    c\n    '
>>> unescape_string('\\\\n')
'\\n'
```

Do know this is *far slower* than using the built-in codec.

Comment: Not my downvote, but its probably because the argument for ```string.decode()``` is wrong

Comment: I'd say it's also over engineered and removes the ability for the asker to learn the fundamentals of something like a "string replace".

Comment: @EugeneK: How is this overengineered? The codec exists *for just this purpose*.

Comment: @EugeneK: that's like saying that using a dictionary is over-engineered when the user really should learn how to build a hash table.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No it's like saying a defaultdict(int) answer is over-engineered when the user could just if key not in dict: dict[key] = 0. One gives a magic answer, the other gives him an answer that's fundamental. That's just my opinion, but I don't down vote anything.

Comment: @EugeneK: I think you are over-applying the term. Using existing tools that fit the purpose is *not* over-engineering. We are not designing a new product here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'll agree that the term over engineered might've been misused in this case.

Comment: @EugeneK: :-) It's okay, just somewhat surprised at the term being applied. Note that `str.replace()` is going to fail in the face of escaped escapes, so `\\\\r`, for example. That should be interpreted as `\\r`, not `\r`.

Comment: @EugeneK: There, added the proper manual way too. Not using `str.replace()` however.

Comment: You wouldn't have to insert `\\\\ ` all over the place to get a single `\\ ` if you use raw strings in `string.replace()`

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight: sure, but then the difference between input and output isn't so clear and visible.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution to this is just to use a str.replace() call

```
s = '\\n    this is a docstring for\\n    the main function.\\n    a,\\n    b,\\n    c\\n    '
s1 = s.replace('\\n','\n')
s1
```

output

```
'\n    this is a docstring for\n    the main function.\n    a,\n    b,\n    c\n    '
```

Comment: Is that the actual output? Because that makes it look like your solution didn't actually work. (they should be on separate lines)

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert_text(text):
    return text.replace("\\n","\n").replace("\\t","\t")


text = '\\n    this is a docstring for\\n    the main function.\\n    a,\\n    b,\\n    c\\n    '
print convert_text(text)
```

output:

```
    this is a docstring for
    the main function.
    a,
    b,
    c
```